# How to swap the thumbnail image on magento 2 products?

Tags: product-images, magento2.4.4, import-products

I have imported the products and product images for my new website. There are more than 5000 products have added.
When assigning product image , backside of the product image was added to main image like below. Manually doing is obviously a nightmare.

[image]

How can i easily swap this for all products? Any idea or scripts highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do it with database queries.
the image attribute value is stored in the `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table.
you can get the image attribute ID with `select from eav_attribute_where attribute_code = 'image' and entity_type_id = (select wntity_type_id from eav_entity_type where entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')`.

With this id you can identify the image attributes values with `select * from` catalog_product_entity_varchar `where attribute_id = {id from above}`.

If you have a special name format for the images that should be set in the image attribute you can try updating this table.

Comment: thank you, i will try this.

Answer (score 0):

I come up with running below script on pub directory to achieve this task. This may help some one in future.

**image_swap.php file**

```
<?php
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';
$params = $_SERVER;
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$productRepository = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
$csv = "sku_vs_image.csv";
if (!empty($argv) && sizeof($argv) > 1) { 
  $csv = $argv[1];
}
if (($handle = fopen($csv, "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 2000, "\t")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    if ($num < 1) {
        continue;
    }
    $sku = explode(',',trim($data[0])); 
    
    $imagePath = $sku[1];

    try {
        $product = $productRepository->get($sku[0]);
        
        $productId = $product->getId();
        $productRepository = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
        
        $product->addImageToMediaGallery('catalog/product'.$imagePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
        $product->save();

        //Get existing image 
        $existingMediaGalleryEntries = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
        
        foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $key => $entry) {
            //Remove the duplicate image after assigning roles
            if($entry->getFile() === $imagePath ){
                unset($existingMediaGalleryEntries[$key]);
            }
        }
        $product->setMediaGalleryEntries($existingMediaGalleryEntries);
        $productRepository->save($product);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo $sku[0].$e->getMessage()."</br>";
        continue;
    }
}
fclose($handle);
}
```

**sku_vs_image.csv** file sample

```
sku_1,/1/6/16-02-08651_1.jpeg
sku_2,/1/6/16-02-05659_1.jpeg
sku_3,/1/6/16-02-08651_1_1.jpeg
```

Update the csv and run the script from root. script first update the image role and create the image, and remove the existing image which assigned the role after.